# How to connect to spark-shell and execute hive queries using java

Tags: java, bigdata

Could you please give me a idea how to connect to spark shell through java code.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Spark Shell is a command line, interactive program (that starts a spark session and a scala REPL to interact with it). Why would you want to connect to an interactive shell program from a Java Application (which is really pretty hard!), when you could either start a Spark session locally in that Java program, or connect it to an existing cluster ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add maven `spark-core` and `spark-sql` dependency in your `pom.xml` :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.12</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-sql_2.12</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.3</version>
</dependency>
```

You will then be able to `@Autowired` a `SparkSession` object (if you are using `Spring boot`) and run your `Spark` operations.